# TYPO3 custom content IRRE (inline content)

Tags: typo3, windows-ce

Is there a solution to get inline elemnts in a custom content element? I only know thd solution to set the page with the data records in the content element where the inline elements are stored.
But i woult like to create a new content element and then put some inline elements directly in it.

Comment: The basic answer is: Yes! Define your IRRE field in the TCA and add it to your content element. Furthermore you might need a data processor in your TypoScript to retrieve the data. For "better" answers it would be good to see what you have so far and what the concrete problem is.

Comment: My first problem is that i need to create a content element with specific fields. I just get the contentn with the field for the data records,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add IRRE items on your content element. You need to create the relation between the content element and the table where the IRRE items are saved and get them via the [DatabaseQueryProcessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/DatabaseQueryProcessor.html).

Here you can get inspired on how you can achieve this:

[How to create custom content elements on TYPO3](https://learn-typo3.com/blog/news-detail/how-to-create-custom-content-elements-on-typo3)

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.